# How does canvas.bind(event, handler) pass event to the event handler?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The primary way of passing arguments to a function in Python is this:

```
def function(x):
    # function definition

function(y)
```

That is, when we call `function` we pass a value to it inside parenthesis.

However, I am using tkinter, and the event `canvas.bind()` method works thus:

```
def event_handler(event):
    # function definition

canvas.bind('event-name', event_handler)
```

That is, when `canvas.bind` calls the method `event_handler`, it seemingly does not pass the argument `'event-name'` to `event_handler` as one would expect (i.e. by doing `event_handler('event-name')`). Instead, it just calls `event_handler` without any arguments.

So how does `event-handler` receive the event argument it is supposed to receive, going by its definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does it just like you expect. In the binding you are giving the *name* of the function to call. When the event fires, the internal tkinter code that processes the event actually calls it just as you would: `event_handler(event)`.